# Grant database-specific privileges not working

Tags: phpmyadmin

okay so I want the user 'test' to have all the privileges on database 'magento' and only 'magento'.
I'm using tables in phpMyadmin for this, and
this should take of it but it doesn't.

[image]

. is there other way to achieve this? or am I doing something wrong?